# What's wrong with the placement of my curly braces?

Tags: r, curly-braces

My program, written in R, has encountered an error with the placement of closing curly braces. The error occurs in the following code:

```
file_list <- list.files()

for (file in file_list){
    data <- read.fit(file)
    # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
    if (!exists("cdata")){
        cdata<-with(data$record, data.frame (lat=position_lat, lon=position_long, speed=(speed/1000*60*60), alt=altitude, HR=heart_rate, time=timestamp)
    }

    # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
    if (exists("cdata")){
        temp_cdata <-with(data$record, data.frame (lat=position_lat, lon=position_long, speed=(speed/1000*60*60), alt=altitude, HR=heart_rate, time=timestamp)
        cdata<-rbind(cdata, temp_cdata)
        rm(temp_cdata)
    }
}
```

I have looked over the code several times and do not see any cause for error, yet I keep getting the following:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"    cdata<-with(data$record, data.frame (lat=position_lat, lon=position_long, speed=(speed/1000*60*60), alt=altitude, HR=heart_rate, time=timestamp)
    }"

# if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
if (exists("cdata")){
    temp_cdata <-with(data$record, data.frame (lat=position_lat, lon=position_long, speed=(speed/1000*60*60), alt=altitude, HR=heart_rate, time=timestamp)
    cdata<-rbind(cdata, temp_cdata)
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"    temp_cdata <-with(data$record, data.frame (lat=position_lat, lon=position_long, speed=(speed/1000*60*60), alt=altitude, HR=heart_rate, time=timestamp)
    cdata"
    rm(temp_cdata)
Warning message:
    In rm(temp_cdata) : object 'temp_cdata' not found
      }
    Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
      }
    Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
```

Comment: you are missing a ")"  at the end of `cdata<-with...`

Comment: Where the error message ends tells you exactly where the error occurs, just fyi

Comment: Also, if you're using RStudio you can use the "insert matching parens" code option and problems like these virtually disappear or are very easy to catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way after fixing `cdata` and `temp_data` parenthesis issue. No need to check `cdata` twice with `exists()`, use simple `if-else`

```
file_list <- list.files()

for (file in file_list){
  data <- read.fit(file)
    # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
    if (!exists("cdata")){
      cdata<-with(data$record, data.frame (lat=position_lat, lon=position_long, speed=(speed/1000*60*60), alt=altitude, HR=heart_rate, time=timestamp))
    }else{
      #append to it
      temp_cdata <-with(data$record, data.frame (lat=position_lat, lon=position_long, speed=(speed/1000*60*60), alt=altitude, HR=heart_rate, time=timestamp))
      cdata<-rbind(cdata, temp_cdata)
      rm(temp_cdata)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing parentheses at the end of both your `with` functions (cdata and temp_cdata)